# Why condition like j!=i is imposed on PDF of hypoexponential distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am currently working on network project in which i have to choose a predetermined number of nodes from entire network as Central Nodes. And this selection is based on the inter contact time between the nodes which follows hypoexponential distribution. Hence the distribution PDF contributes more towards the selection of central node.The PDF of the distribution has C as a metric which is calculated based on math product latex constant. Can anyone elaborate on the PDF and figure out the reason why the conditions are imposed? for reference i have attached the link of the paper in which chapter 4 deals with this question. http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=64770